# Dual boot fedora 23 and Windows 10 issue

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I had Windows 10 installed on my machine. When I decided to also install Fedora 23 using Dual boot, Fedora was working fine, but when I tried to boot Windows 10 I had a problem.

In the grub boot menu there was no option to boot Windows. I tried to find a solution on the internet and I saw it was a common problem and the solution is to change the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file and add it to the grub configuration using `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`. When it finished, a Windows entry appeared in the boot menu, but when I tried to boot it, I receive the following error:

```
error: file `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

`fdisk -l` gives the following output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4100E3EC-6448-11E4-825E-18CF5E1C1030

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1845247   1843200   900M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    1845248   2050047    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3    2050048   2312191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    2312192 352907181 350594990 167.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  352907264 353875967    968704   473M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  353875968 354899967   1024000   500M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  354899968 414562303  59662336  28.5G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x96551baf

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048 1269832126 1269830079 605.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       1269833726 1465147391  195313666  93.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1269833728 1465147391  195313664  93.1G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 10.5 GiB, 11219763200 bytes, 21913600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 3 GiB, 3217031168 bytes, 6283264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

So I think in the `40_custom` file, I have to put the ID of the `/dev/sda2` drive like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry 'Microsoft Windows 10' {
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root '4784-075F'
chainloader /EFI/Microsft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
boot
}
```

I tried it using the `uuid` and (like above) and using the name of the drive but I still get the same error.

If you need some extra information, just ask!
I used [this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166986/116504) to try to fix it, but it won't help.

Comment: I was also having trouble booting into Fedora 23 this morning and thought Windows 10 might be to blame. The trick is to ask someone to take a look at it so that you look foolish when it starts working magically.